# How can I change the labels in this pie chart [plotly]?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to change the labels [2,3,4,5] from my pie chart and instead have them say [Boomer, Gen X, Gen Y, Gen Z] respectively. I can't seem to find a direct way of doing this without changing the dataframe. Is there any way to do this by working through the code I have?

[image: pie chart]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

data = df.groupby("Q10_Ans")["Q4_Agree"].count()

pie, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,6])
labels = data.keys()
plt.pie(x=data, autopct="%.1f%%", explode=[0.05]*4, labels=labels, pctdistance=0.5)
plt.title("Generations that agree data visualization will help with job prospects", fontsize=14);
pie.savefig("DeliveryPieChart.png")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about change the code

`labels = data.keys()`

to

`labels = ['Boomer','Gen X','Gen Y','Gen Z']`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the data structure of your data, so I made a sample data and created a pie chart. Please modify your code to follow this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

# data = df.groupby("Q10_Ans")["Q4_Agree"].count()
data = pd.DataFrame({'Q10_Ans':['Boomer','Gen X','Gen Y','Gen Z'],'Q4_Agree':[2,3,4,5]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,6])
labels = data['Q10_Ans']
ax.pie(x=data['Q4_Agree'], autopct="%.1f%%", explode=[0.05]*4, labels=labels, pctdistance=0.5)
ax.set_title("Generations that agree data visualization will help with job prospects", fontsize=14);
plt.savefig("DeliveryPieChart.png")
```

[image]